# Is there any way to render the Amazon Lex's Response card in asp.net UI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I tried to create my own UI in asp.net which I linked with my Amazon Lex bot. I stucked when I try to pass Response card and it is not displaying anything. I used Lambda to pass the response to LEX.

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].